# Adding pins to MapView

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview, android-mapview

I was wondering how I would add pins to a MapView within an iPhone app. I want to have pins pinned in places that have the word "Tea" in their name and it would be impractical to place each pin in every place that contains that word, so I was wondering if there's some way to make it so that when the MapView is loaded, the pins are pinned into those places. I assume that this would be done with Google's Map API however I'm unsure as to how I'd exactly do this - does anyone know of any tutorials that would show to implement this.

So far, I have a simple view that contains a MapView as well as a corresponding view controller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add instances of `MKAnnotation` to your MKMapView.

```
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

`annotation` is an instance of a class conforming to the MKAnnotation protocol. Read the corresponding documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation

Sample code:

```
@interface MyAnnotation: NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
}

@end

@implementation MyAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title;

- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        coordinate.latitude = 0.0;
        coordinate.longitude = 0.0;
        title = NSLocalizedString(@"Tea");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In your view controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // custom initialiation; create map view
    [self addPin]; // or with parameters, called multiple times, to add several annotations
}

- (void) addPin
{
    MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [ann release];
}
```

Hope this helps.